# Calculate trip time from start and end locations

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

Im working on some kind of riding app. I want to to calculate the trip time.So once the user starts from current location I want to start timer, once the user reaches destination I want to stop timer.

1.How to achieve this from google maps?

2.Also my trip time should be a combination of waiting time and travelled time.How can i get the travel time and wait time separately.(Wait time is some thing but if user waits or stopped at particular location for some time)

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Do you want to calculate how long a trip will take (estimate), or how long a trip actually took (as measured on a device carried by the rider)? If the latter, do you want to automatically detect start/end based on a preselected trip, or just allow the user to tap start/end buttons?

Comment: @jcaron Thanks for reply. driver current location and source location may not be the the same. so once driver reaches the start location i want to start the timer, once the user reaches i want to end the timer

Comment: Well, you need some way to select start and end points (either by tapping on a map or by entering an address), then set up location-based notifications around these locations, make a note of the time you reach each of those, and compute the difference. To exclude wait time you'll have to monitor location updates and/or motion between start and stop to detect when the device is moving or not.

Answer (score 0):

Google MAP serves these purpose precisely. you can get them from the following document. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro

Comment: I want to calculate actual time he took to complete ride. Also is there any way to know  if driver waits or stopped at particular location for some time

Answer (score 0):

There are a whole number of ways baked in to iOS that would allow you to get the time such as the timeIntervalSince1970 function of NSDate.

Foe example, you could simply call this function when the driver picks up/accepts the rider(If they driver will also have your app) and then call the same function and work out the difference when the driver confirms that the ride has finished (Again if the driver will also have your app, similar to Uber).

I would personally suggest getting this set up first before you look at making it smarter by checking when a user has stopped moving etc. Most of the time you'll find that once you get the base of something set up that you have a lot more knowledge of whatever it is that you're working with and that something you thought would be difficult before you started is actually easier than you ever thought.

TLDR. Keep it simple and do everything in small bites